# TaskbarIcon will not show balloon tip with custom icon

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon

I have created a WPF app which is using [WPF NotifyIcon.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon?)

I am unable to get the ShowBalloonTip method to work with a custom Icon. I have tried like this:

```
_icon.ShowBalloonTip("Title", "Message", new Icon("Icons/accept.ico"));
```

Any idea how I can get a notification to work with a custom icon? (Using the built in icons works fine - i.e. using BalloonIcon).

Comment: Is the path to your icon correct?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that is correct. I have also tried using the icon from my TaskbarIcon object which is showing correctly in the tool bar: `_icon.ShowBalloonTip("Title", "Message", _icon.Icon);` No luck with that either

Answer (score 4):

Try using the "Large Icon" overload.

```
   _icon.ShowBalloonTip("Title", "Message", new Icon("Icons/accept.ico"), largeIcon: true);
```

This worked for me.